# @DirtiesContext not working as expected after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.2

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade my application from Spring Boot `v2.1.8` to `v2.2.2`. However, after upgrading some tests start failing.

The pattern of failing tests strongly indicates that `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`, applied on test class, is failing to clear context after each test case.

I am unable to narrow down further. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. With spring boot 2.2.7 not playing nice with Dirties context. In my case, I was using DBUnit to test and it wasn’t resetting the DB.

Adding this annotation fixed it for me:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.ANY)
```